# how can we can show popup(*Size or color is not selected) when size or color is not selected?

Tags: jquery, liquid

[image]
like the image I have shared

I try many time but not happening can someone plz help me out from this

Answer (score 0):

1. add validation when user click on add to bag

for example

```
$('#addtobag').click(function(){

 if($('.size').val() == "")
{
  alert("please select size");
}
else if($('.color').val() == "")
{
   alert("please select color");
}
else
{
   alert("Product has added to bag");
  //button click function
}
```

});